# generate sequence number

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi can any one help me generate version  number based on below table data

ex:

```
book_name      version 
math_1           1
physics_1        3
physics_6        4
chemist_1        1
chemist_2        2
eng_1            1
```

i want a query to rerun below result based on above table data( especially Physics )
expected result

```
book_name      version 
math_1           1
physics_1        1
physics_6        2
chemist_1        1
chemist_2        2
eng_1            1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To produce the new version you need to separate the subject from the level. Once you do that, a simple `ROW_NUMBER()` function does the job.

For example:

```
select x.*,
  row_number() over(partition by subject order by lvl) as new_version
from (
  select t.*,
    substr(book_name, 1, instr(book_name, '_') - 1) as subject,
    to_number(substr(book_name, 1 + instr(book_name, '_'))) as lvl
  from t
) x;
```

Result:

```
  BOOK_NAME   version   SUBJECT   LVL   NEW_VERSION  
 ----------- --------- --------- ----- ------------- 
  chemist_1   1         chemist   1     1            
  chemist_2   2         chemist   2     2            
  eng_1       1         eng       1     1            
  math_1      1         math      1     1            
  physics_1   3         physics   1     1            
  physics_6   4         physics   6     2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=55cfaaa57399d59204bcb2180a186e07).

Answer (score 0):

Similarly (lines #1 - 8 represent sample data; you don't type that. Query that returns result you wanted begins at line #9):

```
SQL> with test (book_name, version) as
  2    (select 'math_1'   , 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'physics_1', 3 from dual union all
  4     select 'physics_6', 4 from dual union all
  5     select 'chemist_1', 1 from dual union all
  6     select 'chemist_2', 2 from dual union all
  7     select 'eng_1'    , 1 from dual
  8    )
  9  select book_name,
 10    version,
 11    row_number() over (partition by regexp_substr(book_name, '[[:alpha:]]')
 12                       order by to_number(regexp_substr(book_name, '\d+$'))
 13                      ) new_version
 14  from test
 15  order by book_name, new_version;

BOOK_NAME    VERSION NEW_VERSION
--------- ---------- -----------
chemist_1          1           1
chemist_2          2           2
eng_1              1           1
math_1             1           1
physics_1          3           1
physics_6          4           2

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem to just want the last digits:

```
select t.*,
       regexp_substr(book_name, '[0-9]+$')
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6fe71e60c4bf397e24e46969d61a5e60) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but no i'm not looking for last digit , want to generate new version number start with  1 for that  physics group